# How to determine required Node.js version for Yarn or npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Given a `package.json` file or corresponding npm or Yarn lockfile (`package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`), is there some automated way to determine the minimum version of Node.js required to satisfy the `engines.node` fields in all `package.json` files for dependencies that should be installed according to said files?

For example, suppose my `package.json` lists dependencies `a` and `b`, where `a` in turn lists dependency `c` in its `package.json`. Suppose that `a` lists `>= 6.90` in its `engines.node` field, `b` lists `>= 8`, and `c` lists `>=10`. What I am looking for is a way to easily determine that Node.js version >= 10 is required to support the dependencies of the hypothetical project using this `package.json`.

The npm CLI has the `npm view` command and Yarn has the similar `yarn info` command, both of which can be used to view the `engines.node` field for a particular package, but these commands do not quite do the trick because:

1. They only deal with 1 package at a time.
2. They do not account for dependencies of dependencies.
3. They do not automatically look through `package.json` or the corresponding lockfiles to get the desired information for all packages that should be installed.